# How to check if there is a strikethrough on some text in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, galen

There are many planbox, which are having same class and ids, inside them there are a number of `<p>` tags and decorated text.

```
<div class="planbox">
   <p class="baseprice">
      <span>
         <strike> $70 </strike>
      </span>
   </p>
   <p> New discount price is etc. </p>
</div>
<div class="planbox">
   <p class="baseprice">
      <span> $70 </span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Now, My test case is - if the base price is strikethrough, only then `<p> 'New discount price ..  </p>` will show, otherwise not.

How to check whether a text is strikethrough or not? And even if we get this how will I check that `<p> New discount.. </p>` should not show if the text is not striked.

As there is no class in `<p>` tag on which I can check whether it displayed or not.

One solution in my mind was - add one dummy class in `<span>` tag and using `findChildren('span.dummyCLass')` it will result all the webelements having dummyClass.

Now I will check whether web-elements have strike tag or not, and this is the place where I got stuck.

Initially, i was thinking of a Jquery solution, but is it possible to do without adding new class and jquery?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: @JeffC I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add a class to any element to accomplish this task. In general, you don't want to edit the HTML. Another issue is... if you can find the element to add a class, then you don't need to add the class to find the element. :)

The way I approach tasks like these is to find the outermost element that contains all the elements that you are interested in. I refer to this as a "container". What you want to do in this case is to find the containers and loop through them looking for the strikethrough price and for the "New discount price..." text.

The containers are `DIV`s with the `planbox` class. The strikethrough price is indicated by the `STRIKE` tag. The "New discount price..." text is in a `P` tag. With this info we can write some code. This is Java because I don't know what language you want and I'm not familiar with the Galen framework.

```
// gets the collection of containers using a CSS selector
List<WebElement> containers = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.planbox"));
// loops through the containers
for (WebElement container : containers)
{
    // determine if the STRIKE tag exists
    boolean strikeExists = !container.findElements(By.tagName("strike")).isEmpty();
    // determine if the "New discount price is..." text exists in the 2nd P tag
    boolean discountPriceExists = container.findElements(By.tagName("p")).get(1).getText().trim().contains("New discount price is");
    // if both are true log a pass, otherwise log a fail
    if (strikeExists && discountPriceExists)
    {
        // log a pass
    }
    else
    {
        // log a fail
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer so the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used much of selenium. But you can port this jquery code to selenium,

```
 //if there is a strike element
 if($(".baseprice span strike").length > 0){
   //next() will select the sibling of the p tag with baseprice class
   $("p.baseprice).next() != undefined){
     return true
   }else{
     return false
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Galen for this. There you can verify certain [CSS properties](http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-spec-language-guide/#CSSProperties).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.